# How correctly to mix output of DirectX app?

Tags: directx, kinect

I'm currently trying to use Kinect in Visual Studio 2010 C++.
I want to learn how mix different sources of DirectX in one.

For instance I get BackgroundRemovalBasic (sample from Kinect SDK 1.8 - extracting player from a scene) and LocalDeformablePRT (sample from DirectX9 SDK2010 sample - the bat flying).

And I'm currently stucked with a problem:
The LocalDeformablePRT sample use 3D and DXUT, while BackgroundRemovalBasic use 2D and constructor.

I mixed two sample in one loop and it works good, but in two different windows.
I tried to share one window (DXUTSetWindow(hWnd, hWnd, hWnd, TRUE); ) but I get black window.
Explain me please, how correctly to mix samples for share one window?
In what point of DirectX engine I should mix it and how?

Below is main part of my working creature (parts which I change from samples):

```
    int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
    {
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D9DeviceAcceptable( IsDeviceAcceptable );
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D9DeviceCreated( OnCreateDevice );
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D9DeviceReset( OnResetDevice );
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D9FrameRender( OnFrameRender );
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D9DeviceLost( OnLostDevice );
    DXUTSetCallbackD3D9DeviceDestroyed( OnDestroyDevice );
    DXUTSetCallbackFrameMove( OnFrameMove );
    DXUTCreateDevice( true, 640, 480 );

    CBackgroundRemovalBasics application; 
    application.Run(hInstance, nCmdShow); // BackgroundRemoval by Kinect

    return DXUTGetExitCode();
    }

    int CBackgroundRemovalBasics::Run(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
    {  
    MSG       msg = {0};
    WNDCLASS  wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(wc));
    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = DLGWINDOWEXTRA;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIconW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APP));
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = DefDlgProcW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"BackgroundRemovalBasicsAppDlgWndClass";
    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc)){return 0;}
    const HANDLE hEvents[] = {m_hNextDepthFrameEvent, m_hNextColorFrameEvent, m_hNextSkeletonFrameEvent, m_hNextBackgroundRemovedFrameEvent};
    HWND hWnd = CreateDialogParamW( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_APP), NULL, (DLGPROC)CBackgroundRemovalBasics::MessageRouter, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this) );
    // DXUTSetWindow(hWnd, hWnd, hWnd, TRUE); I tried...
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow); UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    LoadResourceImage(L"Background", L"Image", m_colorWidth * m_colorHeight * cBytesPerPixel, m_backgroundRGBX);

// MAIN LOOP          
    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
{

    if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) != 0  )
    {
        if( TranslateAccelerator( hWnd, NULL, &msg ) == 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    }
    else   // Render a frame during idle time (no messages are waiting)
    {  
       //--- BackgroundRemoval Kinect ---
MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(_countof(hEvents), hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(m_hNextBackgroundRemovedFrameEvent, 0)){ComposeImage();}
    if ( WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(m_hNextDepthFrameEvent, 0) ){ProcessDepth();}
    if ( WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(m_hNextColorFrameEvent, 0) ){ProcessColor();}
    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(m_hNextSkeletonFrameEvent, 0) ){ProcessSkeleton();}

        //---  The Bat flying -----------
        DXUTRender3DEnvironment();
    }

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: **This is a comment** Did you read this : [Direct2D and Direct3D Interoperability ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370966(v=vs.85).aspx) and this : [Surface Sharing Between Windows Graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee913554(v=vs.85).aspx) ? > Direct2D supports interoperability with Direct3D 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok.

What you want to do is to use the sensor inside the DXUT application. You don't really need to mix both application and share texture. You just need to use one window (from DXUT), and show the BackgroundRemoval texture inside the DXUT renderer.

The BackgroundRemoval sample use a 2D renderer for simplicity. The LocalDeformablePRT sample use a 3D renderer with perspective projection. Also it uses a skybox, which differs from the static image background of the BackgroundRemoval sample. You want to use the skybox or the image background ?

So, i will say you have to extract source code from the BackgroundRemoval sample that only concerned the Kinect sensor. You have to use the code to initialize the Kinect and NuiCreateBackgroundRemovedColorStream.

When you call m_pBackgroundRemovalStream->GetNextFrame, after you have this code :

```
BYTE alpha = 0; 
const int alphaChannelBytePosition = 3; 
for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; ++i) 
{ 
  if (i % cBytesPerPixel == 0) 
  { 
    alpha = pBackgroundRemovedColor[i + alphaChannelBytePosition]; 
  } 

  if (i % cBytesPerPixel != alphaChannelBytePosition) 
  { 
    m_outputRGBX[i] = static_cast<BYTE>(( (UCHAR_MAX - alpha) * m_backgroundRGBX[i] + alpha * pBackgroundRemovedColor[i] ) / UCHAR_MAX ); 
  } 
}
```

Use it to copy the image in a D3DTexture9 and show it with a quad.

Comment: if You have free time - Can You make it? Say to qqqq1961@ya.ru please. I could pay a little. I need in working example for my learning.
Because the "Use it to copy the image in a D3DTexture9 and show it with a quad." - I don't understand still.

Comment: I can do it for free. The problem, i don't have a Kinect sensor. So if you buy me a Kinect and send it to me, i will do it.

Comment: Interesting! Reply me to qqqq1961@ya.ru please.